# Registration in the Duplicate database

Tags: java, swing

My experience with Java is very little, I am making an application that can control me the step to take food in a dining room, what the application does is verify that the fingerprint is in the database, if it is not saved.
The problem is that he is keeping the same mark over and over again, then I describe what happens:

1. Register the first fingerprint and save it correctly.
2. If I register the same footprint, the application informs me that it is already registered.
3. If I register a new fingerprint, at the time of saving I still register the previous fingerprint in the database.

I have attached the code if they can help me.

records in the database

```
public class VerificarParte extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public VerificarParte() {



        try {
         UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
         } catch (Exception e) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Imposible modificar el tema visual", "Lookandfeel inválido.",
         JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
         }
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        txtArea.setEditable(false);

        try {
            RegistrarParte ventana =new RegistrarParte();
            labelId.setText(RegistrarParte.id);
            labelParte.setText(RegistrarParte.parte);
            labelComida.setText(RegistrarParte.comida);
            labelFecha.setText(RegistrarParte.fecha);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VerificarParte.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        panHuellas = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        lblImagenHuella = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        panBtns = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txtArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jPanel5 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        labelId = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        labelFecha = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        labelParte = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        labelComida = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Captura de huella del personal");
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(234, 242, 248));
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowClosing(evt);
            }
            public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowOpened(evt);
            }
        });

        panHuellas.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(234, 242, 248));
        panHuellas.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "HUELLA DIGITAL CAPTURADA", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14), new java.awt.Color(84, 153, 199))); // NOI18N
        panHuellas.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(lblImagenHuella, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 527, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(lblImagenHuella, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 134, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        panHuellas.add(jPanel1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        panBtns.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(234, 242, 248));
        panBtns.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "ACCIONES", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.LEFT, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.TOP, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14), new java.awt.Color(84, 153, 199))); // NOI18N

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(234, 242, 248));

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(84, 153, 199));
        jButton1.setText("REGRESAR");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 512, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(32, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jPanel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(234, 242, 248));

        txtArea.setColumns(20);
        txtArea.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(txtArea);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 507, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout panBtnsLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panBtns);
        panBtns.setLayout(panBtnsLayout);
        panBtnsLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            panBtnsLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(panBtnsLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        panBtnsLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            panBtnsLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(panBtnsLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jPanel5.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(234, 242, 248));
        jPanel5.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "PARTE DE PERSONAL", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.TOP, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14), new java.awt.Color(84, 153, 199))); // NOI18N

        labelId.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        labelId.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(84, 153, 199));
        labelId.setText("jLabel1");

        labelFecha.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        labelFecha.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(84, 153, 199));
        labelFecha.setText("jLabel1");

        labelParte.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        labelParte.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(84, 153, 199));
        labelParte.setText("jLabel2");

        labelComida.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        labelComida.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(84, 153, 199));
        labelComida.setText("jLabel3");

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("ID:");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("FECHA:");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("No. DE UNIDADES:");

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("COMIDA:");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel5Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel5);
        jPanel5.setLayout(jPanel5Layout);
        jPanel5Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(110, 110, 110)
                .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(labelComida)
                            .addComponent(labelParte))
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(labelId, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(labelFecha)
                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                        .addContainerGap())))
        );
        jPanel5Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(53, 53, 53)
                .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(labelId)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(labelFecha)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(labelParte)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(labelComida)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4))
                .addContainerGap(58, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(panBtns, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jPanel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(panHuellas, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(panHuellas, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 175, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(panBtns, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:

            Connection c=con.conectar();

            //Obtiene todas las huellas de la bd

            int idMod = Integer.parseInt(id);
            PreparedStatement identificarStmt = c.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM personal WHERE id_parte="+idMod+" ");
            ResultSet rs = identificarStmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {

                int rowCont = 0; 
                rowCont = rs.getInt(1);
                System.out.println(rowCont);

                int ParteMod = Integer.parseInt(parte);

                System.out.println(ParteMod);

                if (rowCont < ParteMod) {


                    Iniciar();
                    start();
                    EstadoHuellas();


                }else{

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se completo el parte de personal");

                    RegistrarParte ventana = new RegistrarParte();
                    ventana.setVisible(true);
                    this.setVisible(false);


                }

            }

            //btnGuardar.setEnabled(false);
            //btnIdentificar.setEnabled(false);
            //btnVerificar.setEnabled(false);
            //btnSalir.grabFocus();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VerificarParte.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VerificarParte.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }                                 

    private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        stop();
    }                                  

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            //Formularios.AdminPanel form = new Formularios.AdminPanel();
            //form.setVisible(true);
            //this.dispose(); 

    }                                        

//Varible que permite iniciar el dispositivo de lector de huella conectado
// con sus distintos metodos.
private DPFPCapture Lector = DPFPGlobal.getCaptureFactory().createCapture();

//Varible que permite establecer las capturas de la huellas, para determina sus caracteristicas
// y poder estimar la creacion de un template de la huella para luego poder guardarla
private DPFPEnrollment Reclutador = DPFPGlobal.getEnrollmentFactory().createEnrollment();

//Esta variable tambien captura una huella del lector y crea sus caracteristcas para auntetificarla
// o verificarla con alguna guarda en la BD
private DPFPVerification Verificador = DPFPGlobal.getVerificationFactory().createVerification();

//Variable que para crear el template de la huella luego de que se hallan creado las caracteriticas
// necesarias de la huella si no ha ocurrido ningun problema
private DPFPTemplate template;
public static String TEMPLATE_PROPERTY = "template";
protected void Iniciar(){
   Lector.addDataListener(new DPFPDataAdapter() {
    @Override public void dataAcquired(final DPFPDataEvent e) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() {
    EnviarTexto("La Huella Digital ha sido Capturada");
    ProcesarCaptura(e.getSample());
    }});}
   });

   Lector.addReaderStatusListener(new DPFPReaderStatusAdapter() {
    @Override public void readerConnected(final DPFPReaderStatusEvent e) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() {
    EnviarTexto("El Sensor de Huella Digital esta Activado o Conectado");
    }});}
    @Override public void readerDisconnected(final DPFPReaderStatusEvent e) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() {
    EnviarTexto("El Sensor de Huella Digital esta Desactivado o no Conectado");
    }});}
   });

   Lector.addSensorListener(new DPFPSensorAdapter() {
    @Override public void fingerTouched(final DPFPSensorEvent e) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() {
    EnviarTexto("El dedo ha sido colocado sobre el Lector de Huella");
    }});}
    @Override public void fingerGone(final DPFPSensorEvent e) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() {
    EnviarTexto("El dedo ha sido quitado del Lector de Huella");
    }});}
   });

   Lector.addErrorListener(new DPFPErrorAdapter(){
    public void errorReader(final DPFPErrorEvent e){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {  public void run() {
    EnviarTexto("Error: "+e.getError());
    }});}
   });
}

public DPFPFeatureSet featuresinscripcion;
public DPFPFeatureSet featuresverificacion;
public  void ProcesarCaptura(DPFPSample sample)
 {
 // Procesar la muestra de la huella y crear un conjunto de características con el propósito de inscripción.
 featuresinscripcion = extraerCaracteristicas(sample, DPFPDataPurpose.DATA_PURPOSE_ENROLLMENT);

 // Procesar la muestra de la huella y crear un conjunto de características con el propósito de verificacion.
 featuresverificacion = extraerCaracteristicas(sample, DPFPDataPurpose.DATA_PURPOSE_VERIFICATION);

 // Comprobar la calidad de la muestra de la huella y lo añade a su reclutador si es bueno
 if (featuresinscripcion != null)
     try{
     System.out.println("Las Caracteristicas de la Huella han sido creada");
     Reclutador.addFeatures(featuresinscripcion);// Agregar las caracteristicas de la huella a la plantilla a crear

     // Dibuja la huella dactilar capturada.
     Image image=CrearImagenHuella(sample);
     DibujarHuella(image);

     //btnVerificar.setEnabled(true);
     //btnIdentificar.setEnabled(true);

     }catch (DPFPImageQualityException ex) {
     System.err.println("Error: "+ex.getMessage());
     }

     finally {
     try {
         EstadoHuellas();
         // Comprueba si la plantilla se ha creado.
         switch(Reclutador.getTemplateStatus())
         {
             case TEMPLATE_STATUS_READY:    // informe de éxito y detiene  la captura de huellas



                    stop();
                    setTemplate(Reclutador.getTemplate());
                    EnviarTexto("Listo la huella ha sido capturada correctamente ahora puede guardarla");


                    identificarHuella();



                 break;

             case TEMPLATE_STATUS_FAILED: // informe de fallas y reiniciar la captura de huellas
                 Reclutador.clear();
                 stop();
                 EstadoHuellas();
                 setTemplate(null);
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(VerificarParte.this, "La Plantilla de la Huella no pudo ser creada, Repita el Proceso", "Inscripcion de Huellas Dactilares", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                 start();
                 break;
         }
     } catch (IOException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(VerificarParte.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
         }
}

 public  DPFPFeatureSet extraerCaracteristicas(DPFPSample sample, DPFPDataPurpose purpose){
     DPFPFeatureExtraction extractor = DPFPGlobal.getFeatureExtractionFactory().createFeatureExtraction();
     try {
      return extractor.createFeatureSet(sample, purpose);
     } catch (DPFPImageQualityException e) {
      return null;
     }
}

  public  Image CrearImagenHuella(DPFPSample sample) {
    return DPFPGlobal.getSampleConversionFactory().createImage(sample);
}

  public void DibujarHuella(Image image) {
        lblImagenHuella.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
        image.getScaledInstance(lblImagenHuella.getWidth(), lblImagenHuella.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
        repaint();
 }

public  void EstadoHuellas(){
    EnviarTexto("Muestra de Huellas Restantes para Guardar "+ Reclutador.getFeaturesNeeded());
}

public void EnviarTexto(String string) {
        txtArea.append(string + "\n");
}

public  void start(){
    Lector.startCapture();
    EnviarTexto("Utilizando el Lector de Huella Dactilar ");
}

public  void stop(){
        Lector.stopCapture();
        EnviarTexto("No se está usando el Lector de Huella Dactilar ");
}

    public DPFPTemplate getTemplate() {
        return template;
    }

    public void setTemplate(DPFPTemplate template) {
        DPFPTemplate old = this.template;
    this.template = template;
    firePropertyChange(TEMPLATE_PROPERTY, old, template);
    }
    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new VerificarParte().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }



ConexionBD con=new ConexionBD();

 /*
  * Guarda los datos de la huella digital actual en la base de datos
  */




public void identificarHuella() throws IOException{



          try {
              //Establece los valores para la sentencia SQL
              Connection c=con.conectar();

              //Obtiene todas las huellas de la bd

              int idMod = Integer.parseInt(id);
              PreparedStatement identificarStmt = c.prepareStatement("SELECT  huella, id_parte FROM personal WHERE id_parte ="+idMod+" ");
              ResultSet rs = identificarStmt.executeQuery();






              //Si se encuentra el nombre en la base de datos
              while(rs.next()){
                  //Lee la plantilla de la base de datos
                  byte templateBuffer[] = rs.getBytes("huella");
                  //String nombre=rs.getString("nombre");
                  //Crea una nueva plantilla a partir de la guardada en la base de datos
                  DPFPTemplate referenceTemplate = DPFPGlobal.getTemplateFactory().createTemplate(templateBuffer);
                  //Envia la plantilla creada al objeto contendor de Template del componente de huella digital
                  setTemplate(referenceTemplate);
                  // Compara las caracteriticas de la huella recientemente capturda con la
                  // alguna plantilla guardada en la base de datos que coincide con ese tipo
                  DPFPVerificationResult result = Verificador.verify(featuresverificacion, getTemplate());
                  //compara las plantilas (actual vs bd)
                  //Si encuentra correspondencia dibuja el mapa
                  //e indica el nombre de la persona que coincidió.
                  if (result.isVerified()){

                      //crea la imagen de los datos guardado de las huellas guardadas en la base de datos
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La unidad ya tomo sus alimentos");

                        setTemplate(null);
                        VerificarParte ventana = new VerificarParte();
                        ventana.setVisible(true);
                        this.setVisible(false);
                        return;


                  }


              } 

                guardarHuella(); 


          } catch (SQLException e) {
              //Si ocurre un error lo indica en la consola
              System.err.println("Error al identificar huella dactilar."+e.getMessage());
          }finally{
              con.desconectar();
          }

   }


     public void guardarHuella() throws IOException{

     //Obtiene los datos del template de la huella actual
     ByteArrayInputStream datosHuella = new ByteArrayInputStream(template.serialize());
     Integer tamañoHuella=template.serialize().length;

     //Pregunta el nombre de la persona a la cual corresponde dicha huella
     //String nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingresa la clave");
     try {
     //Establece los valores para la sentencia SQL
     Connection c=con.conectar(); //establece la conexion con la BD

        PreparedStatement updatePersonal = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO personal (huella, id_parte) VALUES(?,?)");

        int idmod = Integer.parseInt(id);

        //updatePersonal.setBinaryStream(1, datosHuella,tamañoHuella);
        updatePersonal.setBinaryStream(1, datosHuella,tamañoHuella);
        updatePersonal.setInt(2,idmod); 
        updatePersonal.execute();
        updatePersonal.close();

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Puede Continuar");
         setTemplate(null);   
         VerificarParte ventana = new VerificarParte();
         ventana.setVisible(true);
         this.setVisible(false);

         //btnGuardar.setEnabled(false);
         //btnVerificar.grabFocus();
     } catch (SQLException ex) {
     //Si ocurre un error lo indica en la consola
     System.err.println("Error al guardar los datos de la huella.");
     }finally{
     con.desconectar();
     }
   }
```

[Registration in the Duplicate database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu4gI.png)

Comment: the expectation from the question is not clear, maybe you have to update/restructure the summary.

Comment: In the first step we enter the fingerprint, the application verifies it and if it is not in the database it saves it. When registering the second fingerprint the application verifies in the database and proceeds to save it, but the image of the first fingerprint is being saved. For some reason it does not update the data with the new footprint.